# Which needs to learn Android?

Tags: java, android

In my opinion, if you want to learn android, you must know OS, Network, OPP and Design Pattern well, that 's enough, about you??

Answer (score 2):

You need to know java pretty well and the basic concepts of developing for a mobile device. You also need to have a good grasp on GUI development.

I found Android developer's [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)  to be an awesome resource to learn. This is better than reading the books in the market.

Comment: Can you give me some links to learn GUI design on Mobile

Comment: On the android guide there is a separate page on that. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html